# Modify other property on value change in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

How to set the date2 to the same value as date1 when date1 is set for the first time (more precisely, when date2 is null)? This logic/function should be introduced while mapping a data model to an observable (however, the date2 value should not be set to the date1 value on mapping yet, just when set via data binding).

Data Model

```
var dataModel = {
     'agenda': {
         months: [{date1: null, date2: null}],
     }
}
```

Binding

```
data-bind="value: date1"
```

Mapping

```
var observableModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(dataModel);
```

I have tried to read the Knockout JS documentation but failed to find a way how to intercept updating the date1 value with my own function.

I am aware of `subscribe` but it does provide me with just the new value but not the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add subscribe to your `date1` observable and set `date2` object like this.

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(observableModel.agenda.months(), function(obj){
  obj.date1.subscribe(function(){ date2Handler(obj.date1, obj.date2)});  
});

function date2Handler(date1,date2){
    if(date2()==null)
        date2(date1())
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/newuserjs/1m62wpym/1/

Comment: The date1 value propagation should be done when date1 is set via data binding only, not during mapping. The user case is that in most cases the date2 will be the same as date1 so if the user fills date1 the date2 should be prefilled it. This logic should not be triggered during mapping. By the mentioning mapping I meant, that the function which copies the value should be added during the mapping. Apologize if it was not clear from the question.